# Issue with Inferring Type of Input Parameter in Generic Function

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm encountering a problem with Typescript regarding the inference of types in a generic function.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
type FnObj<I extends z.ZodType> = {
    input: I,
    func: (input: I extends z.ZodType<infer U> ? U : never) => void
}

type Objs<I extends z.ZodType = z.ZodType> = {
    [key: string]: FnObj<I>
}

function createFormDef<FF extends Objs>(formObject: FF) {
    return formObject;
}

createFormDef({
    test: {
        input: z.object({
            d: z.number(),
        }),
        func: (input) => {
            input.dsf // This line is not throwing an error, although it should be typed as {d: number}.
        },
    },
});
```

I've tried remove generic of Objs to make the single key its own type. But it didn't work. as follows: (also removed the zod part)

```
type FnObj<I extends any = any> = {
    input: I,
    func: (input: I) => void
}

type Objs = {
    [key: string]: FnObj
}

function createFormDef(formObject: Objs) {
    return formObject;
}

createFormDef({
    test: {
        input: {
            hello: 10
        },
        func: (input) => {
            input.dsf // still not working, should typed as {hello:number}
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGbg2m) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, Yes it's working and please write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't support [existentially quantified generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), so you can't say "an object whose property values are `FnObj<I>` for *some* `I` I don't care about".  Writing `FnObj<any>` (which is what your `FnObj` becomes with your [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)) doesn't accomplish that, because [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is not safe, and so `FnObj<any>` allows things where `input` and `func` are completely unrelated.

Instead of trying to write such a type, it would be better to say "an object whose property values at key `K` are `FnObj<T[K]>` for a `T` that I specify".  That is, you would [map over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) an object type `T` to get a corresponding `Objs<T>`:

```
type Objs<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]: FnObj<T[K]> }

function createFormDef<T extends object>(formObject: Objs<T>) {
  return formObject;
}
```

Now the compiler can infer `T` from the `formObject` input:

```
const x = createFormDef({
  test: {
    input: {
      hello: 10
    },
    func: (input) => {
      input.dsf // error
    },
  }
});

x.test.input
//     ^?(property) input: { hello: number; }
```

Here `T` is inferred as `{test: {hello: number}}`, and thus `x` is `Objs<T>` which is `{test: FnObj<{hello: number}>}`, and thus the compiler can [contextually type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) the `input` parameter to the `fn` callback as `{hello: number}`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgeQEYCsA8BJAfFAvFAbwCgooBLOMAV2AC4oMAaEqAMyrgGN6AKC6ugwCUeHADcA9mQAmRAL5EioSFGQoAzmgAqUCAA9gEONPVQJqCJ2A58BKAG0A0uThQA1hBATWULQF16eDVtJz8cBSJ2LmAyCVdOACcIAENDGAkEgFsAEQhWbV0DIxMzCyssHlYMzLVLQTVNLSwRYlIk4CoE1yqs2qsAbnlFTjj1YCg9PChElLTq3NYeVqhDMfpl0n4adZZSUgALCAAbI4l6AEYABl2oOWY9tg5uKD5KGhFcHA29reAAOhMPgA9EDdAkEhkbncWAo5EJBkQ9H9Vv9fkQQQ8oAA9AD8PDAEMgCVAIl+6yghxOZygcComSQEAS-VuQA)